# Doctrine 2 - GROUP BY two columns, gets incorrect values

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

In my databases I have table with `tasks` related with `user` table.
I want to get list of task in specific status, grouped by user and status.
It is my query:

```
$this->createQueryBuilder('t')
      ->select('t.assignee, COUNT(t.id) as count, t.state')
      ->join('t.assignee', 'user')
      ->andWhere('t.state IN (:states)')
      ->setParameters([
         'states' => array($states)
      ])
      ->addGroupBy('t.assignee')
      ->addGroupBy('t.state')
      ->getQuery()
      ->getResult()
```

Unfortunately, that query do not return proper records. The result is only one record per every user, although it should returns some records for one user, sorted by task types.
May you help me correct my query?

Answer (score 0):

You must set the groupBy method first and then use addGroupBy method after.

Your code will look like this :

```
$this->createQueryBuilder('t')
      ->select('t.assignee, COUNT(t.id) as count, t.state')
      ->join('t.assignee', 'user')
      ->andWhere('t.state IN (:states)')
      ->setParameters([
         'states' => array($states)
      ])
      ->groupBy('t.assignee')
      ->addGroupBy('t.state')
      ->getQuery()
      ->getResult()
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `andWhere` to `where` too:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$query = $em->getRepository('App:Entity')->createQueryBuilder('t');
$query
      ->select('t.assignee, COUNT(t.id) as count, t.state')
      ->join('t.assignee', 'user')
      ->where($query->expr()->in('t.state', array($states)))
      ->groupBy('t.assignee')
      ->addGroupBy('t.state')
      ->getQuery()
      ->getResult();
```